# Override MVC5 bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Doing my first MVC 5 app and I want to use the included bootstrap UI stuff, but I have some tweeks I want to do, like background colors, floating the nav bar to the right, etc.

If I remember correctly, the CSS that gets rendered is the one read last, so for example in this list, css3 styles will be the ones rendered (assuming the contents are identical):

```
css1
css2
css3
```

So, if I want to override certain parts of the bootstrap.css file, should I just make an override.css and put it last in the bundle?  Or is there a better way to do it?

Also, when I am done developing and I switch to the min versions of the css and js libraries, will my overrides still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your css file after the bootstrap css. You already found the answer yourself.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted make sure there was nothing different, or "bootstrap specific".  Thanks.

Comment: @BattlFrog Bootstrap isn't anything special. It uses a combination of CSS and javascript to do what it does. You can treat it just like any other plugin.